# LINQ query is returning list when its not necessary

Tags: c#, linq, return, blazor-server-side

So I have a product table which is displaying my list of products. I have a view button in the table for each row so that the user can see additional information about that specific product. To do so the button passes the id of the product for which the button has been pressed. This will allow me to search my database a find the record to display this data. I know that each product has a unique ID so I only need to return a single record.

I have tried to use:

```
  private void ViewProductDetails(int id)
    {
        product = productService.GetProductID(id);
      
        ViewProductPopup = true;
    }  



public Product GetProductByID(int id)
        {
            using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return context.Products
                    .Where(x => x.ProductId == id);
            }
        }
```

But that isn't working I'm getting an 'Cannot implicilty convert type system.linq.iquertable<app.models.product> to app.models.product. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing cast?)' error. So I'm having to use a list of type Product which doesn't make sense when I'm only returning one value:

```
  private void ViewProductDetails(int id)
    {
        productList = productService.GetProductID(id);
        selectedProduct = productList[0]; 
        ViewProductPopup = true;
    }  



public List<Product> GetProductByID(int id)
        {
            using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return context.Products
                    .Where(x => x.ProductId == id)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

In my models I have:

```
public partial class ProductFinderContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductFinderContext ()
    {
    }

    public ProductFinderContext (DbContextOptions<ProductFinderContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

   

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
```

Is this my issue??

Comment: The error message you posted: `Cannot implicilty convert type system.linq.iquertable<app.models.product> to app.models.product`. In other words: `IQueryable<Product>` ( a list of Product entities) can not be converted into `Product` (one Product entity). Use `First()`, `Single()` (or their `OrDefault()` variants) to return a single item.

Comment: Just want to add a slight additional question:
At one point I want to return every product from the product table which matches the searched name. Does this look correct?

 public List<Product> GetProductByName(string name, bool retired)
{
  return context.Products  
                             .Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(trimName))
                             .Where(x => x.DateRetired != null)
                             .OrderBy(x => x.ProductName)
                             .ToList();
}

Comment: off-topic, but to your slight additional question: [good read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It has some  restrictions though.

Comment: @Imogen it doesn't look like you are using the `retired` parameter. Otherwise the syntax seems correct, though you can use a single expression: `.Where(x=> x.DateRetired != null && x.ProductName.Contains(trimName)).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>.Where()` returns a query which filters its source according to the expression provided.

If you know that it will produce a single element, you need to call an appropriate method: `Single()` if the query is guaranteed to return strictly one element; `SingleOrDefault()` if the result can be either single or empty; `First()` if the query may produce several results but you only need one; `FirstOrDefault()` if the result can be empty as well.

You may either chain these methods after `Where()`, or pass the expression directly to them:

```
context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).Single()
```

and

```
context.Products.Single(x => x.ProductId == id)
```

should produce identical result.